# Add a link into a drupal header and table

Tags: 7

I am currently in the process of creating a free sports betting site, and I would be able to manage the matches. For this, I create a table with the data from my table, but I would add a column to manage the matches, to remove them or modify them. Outside, I do not like to add a link in the header, for exemple:

```
 l(t('Modify'), 'link/modi');
```

Here is my actual code:

```
    function get_rencontre_all(){

    $header = array(
    array('data' => 'journee', 'field' => 'journee' ),
    array('data' => 'eq1', 'field' => 'eq1'),
    array('data' => 'eq2', 'field' => 'eq2'),
    array('data' => 'stade', 'field' => 'stade'),
    array('data' => 'date', 'field' => 'date'),
    array('data'=>'Opérations', 'colspan' => 1),
    );

    db_set_active('sport_db');
    $query = db_select('rencontre', 'r')->fields('r');

    $sorter = $query->extend('TableSort') //création de l'objet TableSort
    ->orderByHeader($header); //détermination du trier
    $result = $sorter->execute(); //exécution du TableSort
    db_set_active();
    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //revoie d'un tableau de lignes



}

function modulesport_page_rencontre_manage(){
    $rows = get_rencontre_all();
    //header qui définit les colonnes et les champs associés
    $header = array(
    array('data' => 'Journée', 'field' => 'journee' ),
    array('data' => 'Equipe domicile', 'field' => 'eq1'),
    array('data' => 'Equipe exterieur', 'field' => 'eq2'),
    array('data' => 'Stade', 'field' => 'stade'),
    array('data' => 'Date', 'field' => 'date'),
    array('data'=>'Opérations', 'colspan' => 1),


    );

    $page_array = array(
    'titre' => array(
    '#prefix' => '<h1>',
    '#suffix' => '</h1>',
    '#markup' => 'Liste des rencontres',
    ),
    'tableau' => array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows'=> $rows,
    ),
    );
    return $page_array;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning **returning** `$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, You need to loop the result and add a link to the array like :

```
$rows = array();

foreach ($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
  $rows[] = $row + array('link' => l('MyLinkText', 'mylinkhere'));
}

return $rows;
```

Comment: great, it works ! thx!